# Array of arrays in a Perl object

Tags: arrays, perl, perl-data-structures

I'm trying to use an array of arrays in a Perl object and am still not getting how it works.

Here is the constructor:

```
sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = {};
  $self->{AoA} = [];
  bless($self, $class);
  return $self;
}
```

And here is the part of code which inserts stuff into AoA:

```
push (@{$self->{AoA}}[$row], $stuff);
```

I still can't find anything on the way to define an array of arrays in the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to define AoA in a constructor - merely the topmost arrayref. As far as the blessed hash is concerned, the AoA is merely an arrayref.

Your constructor is perfect.

To insert, you do 2 things:

```
# Make sure the row exists as an arrayref:
$self->{AoA}->[$row] ||= []; # initialize to empty array reference if not there.
# Add to existing row:
push @{ $self->{AoA}->[$row] }, $stuff;
```

Or, if you are adding a known-index element, simply

```
$self->{AoA}->[$row]->[$column] = $stuff;
```

Your problem with doing `push @{$self->{AoA}}[$row]` was that you dereferenced the array 1 level too early.

Comment: Then what do I need to do besides pushing stuff in one of the arrays? Or am I pushing the wrong way?

Comment: @claferri - updated, please check if this answers. Sorry, saved too early